# Using matrix structure to speed up matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix-multiplication

Suppose that I have an `N-by-K` matrix `A`, `N-by-P` matrix `B`. I want to do the following calculations to get my final `N-by-P` matrix `X`.

```
X(n,p) = B(n,p) - dot(gamma(p,:),A(n,:))
```

where

```
gamma(p,k) = dot(A(:,k),B(:,p))/sum( A(:,k).^2 )
```

In MATLAB, I have my code like

```
for p = 1:P
    for n = 1:N
        for k = 1:K
            gamma(p,k) = dot(A(:,k),B(:,p))/sum(A(:,k).^2);
        end
        x(n,p) = B(n,p) - dot(gamma(p,:),A(n,:));
    end
end
```

which are highly inefficient since it uses three for loops! Is there a good way to speed up this code?

Comment: I think you made a typo...What is `s`? And what is `j`?

Comment: Also, don't use the variable name `gamma`, you are overwriting matlab's built-in gamma function...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `bsxfun` for the division and matrix multiplication for the loops:

```
gamma = bsxfun(@rdivide, B.'*A, sum(A.^2));
x = B - A*gamma.';
```

And here is a test script

```
N = 3;
K = 4;
P = 5;

A = rand(N, K);
B = rand(N, P);

for p = 1:P
    for n = 1:N
        for k = 1:K
            gamma(p,k) = dot(A(:,k),B(:,p))/sum(A(:,k).^2);
        end
        x(n,p) = B(n,p) - dot(gamma(p,:),A(n,:));
    end
end

gamma2 = bsxfun(@rdivide, B.'*A, sum(A.^2));
X2 = B - A*gamma2.';

isequal(x, X2)
isequal(gamma, gamma2)
```

which returns

```
ans =
     1
ans =
     1
```

Comment: +1: Definitely cleaner, and faster too. Even looks a bit like the plain-vector formula this way :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try to learn how to implement bsxfun!

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me like you can hoist the gamma calculations out of the loop; at least, I don't see any dependencies on N in the gamma calculations.

So something like this:

```
for p = 1:P
    for k = 1:K
        gamma(p,k) = dot(A(:,k),B(:,p))/sum(A(:,k).^2);
    end
end
for p = 1:P
    for n = 1:N
        x(n,p) = B(n,p) - dot(gamma(p,:),A(n,:));
    end
end
```

I'm not familiar enough with your code (or matlab) to really know if you can merge the two loops, but if you can:

```
for p = 1:P
    for k = 1:K
        gamma(p,k) = dot(A(:,k),B(:,p))/sum(A(:,k).^2);
    end
    for n = 1:N
        x(n,p) = B(n,p) - dot(gamma(p,:),A(n,:));
    end
end
```

Comment: AFAIK, a merge like this should be possible in *any* language ^_^

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis - I wasn't sure there were any implicit dependencies across values of p (e.g., whether gamma(p+1) depended on gamma(p)).  If that was true, then separate loops would be required.

Comment: how can that be if gamma does not appear on the rhs?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis - implicitly via A & B.  (Again, I know *nothing* about Matlab or its notation.)

Answer (score 0):

bxfun is slow...
How about something like the following (I might have a transpose wrong)

```
modA = A * (1./sum(A.^2,2)) * ones(1,k);
gamma = B' * modA;
x = B - A * gamma';
```